# Combine Arrays into One Multidimensional Array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to combine arrays into one single multidimensional array. There could be more than 5 arrays that needs to be combined so I need a code that will automatically combine all arrays no matter how many they are. I tried `array_merge` but it requires manual defining of arrays in comma formatted parameters.

The code to convert is:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Item 1
    [slug] => item-slug-1
    [parent] => 0
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => Item 2
    [slug] => item-slug-2
    [parent] => 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [name] => Item 3
    [slug] => item-slug-3
    [parent] => 2
)
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [name] => Item 4
    [slug] => item-slug-4
    [parent] => 3
)
Array
(
    [id] => 5
    [name] => Item 5
    [slug] => item-slug-5
    [parent] => 3
)
```

And this is how I would like it to look:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        {
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Item 1
            [slug] => item-slug-1
            [parent] => 0
        }

    [1] => Array
        {
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Item 2
            [slug] => item-slug-2
            [parent] => 1
        }

    [2] => Array
        {
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Item 3
            [slug] => item-slug-3
            [parent] => 2
        }

    [3] => Array
        {
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Item 4
            [slug] => item-slug-4
            [parent] => 3
        }

    [4] => Array
        {
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Item 5
            [slug] => item-slug-5
            [parent] => 3
        }
)
```

Here is how the arrays are generated:

1. I receive a response JSON from the server that looks like this:

   `[{"slug":"item-slug-1","name":"Item 1","id":1},{"slug":"item-slug-2","name":"Item 2","id":2},{"slug":"item-slug-3","name":"Item 3","id":3,"children":[{"slug":"item-slug-4","name":"Item 4","id":4},{slug":"item-slug-5","name":"Item 5","id":5}]}]`
2. I decode the JSON then convert it to an array like this:

   `$categories_obj = json_decode( $_POST['order'] );
   $categories_arr = json_decode(json_encode( $categories_obj ), true);`
3. I created a function that walks through each item so it would be easier to insert into my database:

   ```
   function walk_and_update($data, $parent = 0, $count = 0) {

     if( is_array($data) ) {
       $combine = array();
       /* The arrays are generated here */
        foreach( $data as $key => $row ) {
           $formatted = array(
               'id'        =>  $row['id'],
               'name'      =>  $row['name'],
               'slug'      =>  $row['slug'],
               'parent'    =>  $parent
           );

           print_r( $formatted );

            /* My SQL update is here */

           if( isset( $row['children'] ) ) {
               walk_and_update( $row['children'], $row['id'], $count );
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }
4. Then I use the function like this:

   `walk_and_update( $categories_arr );`

Comment: What did you tried? Show your code.

Comment: If you read carefully, I mentioned trying array_merge. Do you still need to see the code for that?

Comment: `array_merge` cannot help to get your expected output. Look into my answer.

Comment: What's the purpose of `$categories_arr = json_decode(json_encode( $categories_obj ), true);`?

Comment: It converts all objects to arrays. It may seem weird but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$arr1 = Array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Item 1',
    'slug' => 'item-slug-1',
    'parent' => 0);

$arr2 = Array(
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Item 2',
    'slug' => 'item-slug-2',
    'parent' => 1);
$arr3 = Array(
    'id' => 3,
    'name' => 'Item 3',
    'slug' => 'item-slug-3',
    'parent' => 2);
$new_arr = array();    
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
    $var_name = 'arr'.$i;
    array_push($new_arr,$$var_name);
}    
echo "<pre>";print_r($new_arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Item 1
            [slug] => item-slug-1
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Item 2
            [slug] => item-slug-2
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Item 3
            [slug] => item-slug-3
            [parent] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Your code can only handle 3 items. If the number of array grows, I will have to update your code from time to time. As I stated on my question above: I need a code that will automatically combine all arrays no matter how many they are.

Comment: That is why I ask your code to see how do you construct the one dimension arrays.

Comment: put `array_push($combine,$formatted); print_r($combine);` lines before or after the print_r($formatted ); statement.

Answer (score 0):

you could make function to handle the array, then return expected array to multidimensional array.

can i know first, that the array you want to merging , did they produce one by one or just one time that can produce many array ?

```
//you could do this if your array produces one time only
$counter = 0;
$new_array=array();
foreach (your array as $key => $val)
{
   $new_array[$counter]['id']= $val['id'];
   $new_array[$counter]['name']= $val['name'];
   $new_array[$counter]['slug']= $val['slug'];
   $new_array[$counter]['parent'] = $val['parent'];
   $counter++;
}



//if your array produces more than one time
function main ()
{
$data['counter']=0;
$data['newarray']=array();

$data = $this->mergin_array(your array,$data['counter'])

}

function merging_array(your array,$counter)
{
   $data = array();
   $counter_new = $counter;
   foreach(your array as $key => $val)
   {
      $data['newarray'][$counter]['id'] = $val['id'];
      $data['newarray'][$counter]['name'] = $val['name'];
      $data['newarray'][$counter]['slug'] = $val['slug'];
      $data['newarray'][$counter]['parent'] = $val['parent'];
      $counter_new++;
   }
   $data['counter'] = $counter_new;

   return $data;

}
```

so no matter how many you use , when you access the $data['newarray'] in your main function it will get you the combined for many array

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. I added details on how the arrays are generated. Please update your code if necessary. Thanks